# Error when trying to use nbconvert to create pdf from ipynb

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am relatively new to python and I do not know how to debug. I have a `.ipynb` that I am trying to convert to a pdf file. When I run this in the command line I am getting the following errors.

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook HW1_notebook.ipynb to pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 528, in get
value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'command'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 528, in get
value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'inkscape'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\svg2pdf.py", line 67, in _inkscape_default
rkey = winreg.OpenKey(wr_handle, "SOFTWARE\\Classes\\inkscape.svg\\DefaultIcon")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I found this issue reported on [github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3499) which I know isn't the same error, but I followed the things that worked for other people with no luck fixing my issue. I tried reinstalling Inkscape. I really don't know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know to convert `ipynb` to `pdf` you need LaTeX, which I guess you've installed. A quick and simple way is to simply save it as `HTML` and then print that file as PDF.

Comment: Yea, I do have LaTeX installed. Converting to HTML works fine, so I might use that if I need to, but I would like to understand the errors that I am getting.

Comment: On windows, nbconvert uses inkscape to convert svg files to eps format for LaTeX. Do you have inkscape installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have inkscape installed.